# PHP - BBCode parser - Parse both bbcode link tag and not tagged link

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, bbcode

I need to do this :

when a user insert a BBCode tag, with preg_replace and regex i do some trasformation.

e.g.

```
function forumBBCode($str){
   $format_search=array(
      '#\[url=(.*?)\](.*?)\[/url\]#i'
   );

   $format_replace=array(
      '<a class="lforum" target="_blank" href="$1">$2</a>'
   );

   $str=preg_replace($format_search, $format_replace, $str);
   $str=nl2br($str);
   return $str;
}
```

now i want also this : when a user insert a normal text with a link, this must be trasformed too. i can't do this trought preg_replace function, because if i write a code as

```
$format_search
'#(www\..*?)#i'

$format_replace
'<a class="lforum" target="_blank" href="$1">$1</a>'
```

it will convert the link 2 time (in the [url] and when the link is without this tag).

so i think to this function :

```
    function checkLinks($string) {
    $arrelab="";
    $arr=split(' |\r\n', $string);
    for($i=0; $i<sizeof($arr); $i++) {
        echo $i." - ".$arr[$i]."<br/>";
        if ((strpos($arr[$i], 'www.')!==false) or (strpos($arr[$i], 'http://')!==false) or (strpos($arr[$i], 'ftp://')!==false)) {
            if (strpos($arr[$i], '[url=')===false) {
                $arr[$i]='<a class="lforum" target="_blank" href="'.$arr[$i].'">'.$arr[$i].'</a>';
            }
        }

        $arrelab=$arrelab." ".$arr[$i];
    }
    return $arrelab;
}
```

the problem is that i need a split as for the newline, as for the empty space.
any help would be appreciated.

p.s. sorry for my bad english :)

cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's easy to workaround with a lookbehind assertion.

```
preg_replace('#(?<![>/"])((http://)?www.........)#im', '<a href="$1">$1</a>'
```

Thus the regex will skip any URL enclosed in " or > or preceeded by /
It's a workaround, not a solution.

PS: target="_blank" is user pestering. Cut it out.

Comment: uhm, I don't understand what do you mean exactly with that code.
if I have a text doesn't enclosed with " or > the expression is not evalutated?

should be nice a regex that doesn't evalutate "http://" text if it have the string [url=, but i cannot do it...

Comment: What this regex does is to ensure that the url is not already enclosed in a link already. Run it *after* the `[url=` regex.

Comment: ah ok, now i understand what he means :) nice one, it seems to be good :)

ps1. if i want "all characters permitted" after www this should be good no? www\..?*
but it seems to fault...

ps2. if i want both http and ftp? i write (?:http|ftp) instead of (http://) ?

Comment: No, I edited my answer with the regex you would use. (Accept mario's though if you use it.)

Comment: tnx mario and aaron :) nice shoot!

p.s. why this isn't a solution? just for curiosity...

Comment: Because it works around the problem rather than directly solving it. Solving it would mean there is no collision in the first place.

Comment: yeah, but for my problem is enough :) NBBC would be the solution, but i prefeer don't use external libraries :)

Answer (score 2):

The easiest option would be to parse the plain-text urls first and ensure they don't come immediately after an equals sign.

Update from Marios:

`preg_replace('#(?<![>/"])(((http|https|ftp)://)?www[a-zA-Z0-9\-_\.]+)#im', '<a href="$1">$1</a>'`

Comment: There I fixed the non greedy option.

Comment: yeah, it rocks! to be honest, i don't have understand why it work, but i will learn it as exercise for regex! tnx again to you and mario :)

Answer (score 1):

Your problem can be identified by reading your title.. **parsing** in combination with  **regex**

You can't 'parse' html or bb-code with a regular expression because they are not regular languages.

You should write (or find) a bb-code parser instead of using regular expressions.

Google's first result for a BB-code parser is [NBBC: The New BBCode Parser](http://nbbc.sourceforge.net/). But I've never used it so I can't comment on the quality.

Answer (score 1):

There is an easier way to do this.  I have created a walk through in the RedBonzai Developers blog.  The link to it is here:  http://www.redbonzai.com/blog/web-development/how-to-create-a-bb-codes-function-in-php/

Let me know if you have any questions.

RedBonzai