# Retrieving url from BBCode, discard everything else

Tags: php, regex, bbcode

I'm looking to strip all but the Flickr photo page URL from a block of BBCode, using the following as an example:

```
[url=http://www.flickr.com/photos/vrfan/6821895917/][img]http://farm8.staticflickr.com/7025/6821895917_a372a271a2_z.jpg[/img][/url]
[url=http://www.flickr.com/photos/vrfan/6821895917/]Y159 being sanded at Daylesford[/url] by [url=http://www.flickr.com/people/vrfan/]VRfan[/url], on Flickr
```

All I want is the value of the first `[url]` tag `(http://www.flickr.com/photos/vrfan/6821895917/)` - everything else can be removed.

Hopefully a regex wizard can help me out on this :)

Cheers,

Michael.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3215907/1196954 - just modify his first example to suit your needs.

Comment: After a bit of playing around I think I've got it working. Thanks for the pointer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `substr()` too combined with `strpos()` instead of Regex.

```
$matches = array();
$f = strpos($str, '[url=');
while ($f)
{
    $end = strpos($str, ']', $f);
    $f += 5;
    $matches[] = substr($str, $f, $end - $f);
    $f = strpos($str, '[url=', $end);
}
var_dump($matches);
// Regex Solution
preg_match_all('/\[url=(.+?)\]/i', $str, $matches);
var_dump($matches[1]);
```

Comment: Thanks, definitely along the right track :) However, the string could be in the middle of a larger string (it's for a discussion forum post). I can't think of a way to find all occurrences of the Flickr BBcode within a post, and apply your suggested code to each occurrence.

Comment: I have made some changes to the original code. Apparently there was a bug in it, the new code should work fine. I've also added another solution that uses Regex.